# Typescript error in Mongodb update query operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongodb and getting a typescript error when i tried to push array of objects into mongodb using push method. For that i am using wrapper mongdb service.

```
public saveRental = () => {
    return this.connector
      .connect()
      .then(() => {
        return this.connector.update(
          "polcyData", // collection name
          { _id: "dummyid" },
          { "$push": { "myArray": { "field1": "abc", "field2": "def" } } },
        );
      });
};
```

This is the error i am getting when hover $push method:

```
(property) $push?: PushOperator<any> | undefined
Type '{ myArray: { field1: string; field2: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PushOperator<any>'.
  Type '{ myArray: { field1: string; field2: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<any, any[]>'.
    Property 'myArray' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '{ field1: string; field2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1256, 5): The expected type comes from property '$push' which is declared here on type 'UpdateQuery<any>'
```

This is the update method params:

```
update(collectionName: string, filter: MongoClient.FilterQuery<any>, update: MongoClient.UpdateQuery<any>, options?: MongoClient.UpdateOneOptions): Promise<any>;
```

This is the UpdateQuery type

```
/** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update */
export type UpdateQuery<TSchema> = {
    /** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/ */
    $currentDate?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, Date, true | { $type: 'date' | 'timestamp' }>;
    $inc?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, number>;
    $min?: MatchKeysAndValues<TSchema>;
    $max?: MatchKeysAndValues<TSchema>;
    $mul?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, number>;
    $rename?: { [key: string]: string };
    $set?: MatchKeysAndValues<TSchema>;
    $setOnInsert?: MatchKeysAndValues<TSchema>;
    $unset?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, any, ''>;

    /** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/ */
    $addToSet?: SetFields<TSchema>;
    $pop?: OnlyFieldsOfType<TSchema, any[], 1 | -1>;
    $pull?: PullOperator<TSchema>;
    $push?: PushOperator<TSchema>;
    $pullAll?: PullAllOperator<TSchema>;

    /** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-bitwise/ */
    $bit?: {
        [key: string]: { [key in 'and' | 'or' | 'xor']?: number };
    };
};
```

Can anybody help me with this? Any help would be really appreciated. The error is coming only for update array operators:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array

Comment: Did you try : { "myArray": { "$push": { "field1": "abc", "field2": "def" } } },

Comment: @matthPen yes but still getting error: Argument of type '{ myArray: { $push: { field1: string; field2: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdateQuery<any>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myArray' does not exist in type 'UpdateQuery<any>'.

Comment: {$set:{ "myArray": { "$push": { "field1": "abc", "field2": "def" } } }} ?

Comment: @matthPen this time typescript error gine, but i am not able to save its throwing error: "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$push' in 'myArray.$push' is not valid for storage."

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue, maybe check your node version.

I had this issue because my current local node version wasn't the version set in the `package.json`

Check if you have a node version specified in your `package.json`

```json
"engines": {
    "node": "^15.7.0"
}
```

Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

```
rm -Rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Set your correct node version

```
echo "v15.7.0" > .nvmrc
nvm install
nvm use
```

And finally reinstall packages

```
npm install
```